# Normalize nested JSON into multiple tables

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, normalization

I have a table where each row contain nested JSON. I want to normalize this JSON into multiple tables with data.

For example below is the JSON for 1 row.

```
{
   "Arn":"UNLQ5HFPVXMX7",
   "Merchant":"UNL",
   "Aun":"aad9561d-17bc-4280-a44f-7fd4cdb2c57a",
   "ExternalArn":"b7e6d3da-4b63-44a8-adfc-884cce34288d",
   "Status":"Commenced",
   "PageIdentifier":"ValidationResult",
   "ProductRate":{
      "RollRate":false,
      "IsFromRate":false
   },
   "Contacts":[
      {
         "Contact":{
            "FirstName":"Lotsa",
            "Surname":"Deductibles",
            "Pun":"b5c648c5-0573-46b0-bc9d-4c4e24cbb1f1",
            "Dependants":2,
            "Emails":[
               {
                  "EmailAddress":"1d507ac2-0631-4d3d-906b-5e473b71cedc",
                  "Type":"PERSONAL",
                  "Id":85885,
                  "CreatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:53.127529+00:00",
                  "CreatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
                  "LastUpdatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:53.1275294+00:00",
                  "LastUpdatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
                  "RowVersion":"AAAAABhpD4k="
               }
            ],
            "PhoneNumbers":[
               {
                  "Type":"MOB",
                  "PhoneNumber":"+61403917776"
               }
            ],
            "TrackingIdentifiers":[
               
            ],
            "Id":89684,
            "CreatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:53.078947+00:00",
            "CreatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
            "LastUpdatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:53.0789472+00:00",
            "LastUpdatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
            "RowVersion":"AAAAABhpD4g="
         },
         "Dependants":2,
         "MaritalStatus":"MARRIED",
         "Type":"PA",
         "ApplicationDocumentIds":[
            
         ],
         "DocumentProvider":"EXT",
         "Assets":[
            {
               "Type":"CASH"
            }
         ],
         "Expenses":[
            {
               
            }
         ],
         "Incomes":[
            {
               "Type":"SAL",
               "Total":100000.0
            }
         ],
         "Employment":[
            {
               "BusinessName":"Nicks Bank",
               "Type":"CURRENT",
               "EmploymentType":"UN",
               "SalaryFrequency":"ANNUAL"
            }
         ],
         "PropertyAssets":[
            {
               "RentalIncome":1500.0,
               "MonthlyRepayment":2000.0,
               "OutstandingBalance":400000.0,
               "Usage":"IL",
               "Address":{
                  "CombinedAddress":"82 Hay St, HAYMARKET, NSW 2000"
               },
               "OwnershipPercentage":1.0
            },
            {
               "RentalIncome":2000.0,
               "MonthlyRepayment":2400.0,
               "OutstandingBalance":500000.0,
               "Usage":"IL",
               "Address":{
                  "CombinedAddress":"U 1 1 Malthouse Lane, Melbourne VIC 3000"
               },
               "OwnershipPercentage":0.5
            }
         ],
         "Liabilities":[
            {
               "Type":"CCL"
            },
            {
               "Type":"LCB"
            },
            {
               "Type":"OLB"
            },
            {
               "Type":"OLR"
            }
         ],
         "HasHecsDebt":true,
         "ResidentialStatus":"RENT",
         "Id":120028,
         "CreatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:53.1723177+00:00",
         "CreatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
         "LastUpdatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:53.1723178+00:00",
         "LastUpdatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
         "RowVersion":"AAAAABhpD5g="
      },
      {
         "Contact":{
            "FirstName":"Fewa",
            "Surname":"Deductibles",
            "Pun":"e0f64678-b116-4354-9c6b-70a31d966bf3",
            "Dependants":0,
            "Type":"OPPORTUNITY",
            "Emails":[
               {
                  "EmailAddress":"abcde-fghijk",
                  "Type":"PERSONAL",
                  "Id":85886,
                  "CreatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:54.5431097+00:00",
                  "CreatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
                  "LastUpdatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:54.54311+00:00",
                  "LastUpdatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
                  "RowVersion":"AAAAABhpD5M="
               }
            ],
            "PhoneNumbers":[
               {
                  "Type":"MOB",
                  "PhoneNumber":"+12345678",
                  "Id":87908,
                  "CreatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:54.547373+00:00",
                  "CreatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
                  "LastUpdatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:54.5473733+00:00",
                  "LastUpdatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
                  "RowVersion":"AAAAABhpD5Q="
               }
            ],
            "TrackingIdentifiers":[
               
            ],
            "Id":89685,
            "CreatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:54.5362658+00:00",
            "CreatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
            "LastUpdatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:54.536266+00:00",
            "LastUpdatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
            "RowVersion":"AAAAABhpD5I="
         },
         "Dependants":2,
         "MaritalStatus":"MARRIED",
         "Type":"SA",
         "ApplicationDocumentIds":[
            
         ],
         "DocumentProvider":"EXT",
         "Expenses":[
            {
               "Total":0.0
            }
         ],
         "Incomes":[
            {
               "Type":"SAL",
               "Total":90000.0
            }
         ],
         "Employment":[
            {
               "BusinessName":"Nicks Bank",
               "Type":"CURRENT",
               "EmploymentType":"UN",
               "SalaryFrequency":"ANNUAL"
            }
         ],
         "PropertyAssets":[
            {
               "RentalIncome":2000.0,
               "MonthlyRepayment":2400.0,
               "OutstandingBalance":500000.0,
               "Usage":"IL",
               "Address":{
                  "CombinedAddress":"U 1 1 Malthouse Lane, Melbourne VIC 3000"
               },
               "OwnershipPercentage":0.5
            }
         ],
         "Liabilities":[
            {
               "Type":"CCL"
            },
            {
               "Type":"LCB"
            },
            {
               "Type":"OLB"
            },
            {
               "Type":"OLR"
            }
         ],
         "HasHecsDebt":false,
         "ResidentialStatus":"RENT",
         "DriversLicense":{
            
         },
         "Id":120029,
         "CreatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:54.5511511+00:00",
         "CreatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
         "LastUpdatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:54.5511512+00:00",
         "LastUpdatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
         "RowVersion":"AAAAABhpD5o="
      }
   ],
   "FinancialValidationProvider":"EXT",
   "IsFirstHomeBuyer":false,
   "IsConditionalLoan":false,
   "IsAvmUsable":false,
   "IsPcUsable":false,
   "IsEvrUsable":false,
   "SelfEmployedLoan":false,
   "BusinessLoan":false,
   "Id":230417,
   "CreatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:53.0229128+00:00",
   "CreatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
   "LastUpdatedOn":"2023-01-02T22:48:54.5795498+00:00",
   "LastUpdatedBy":"6qpgj5bpnm7eg0eo6lfvc9og33@tictochomeloans.com",
   "RowVersion":"AAAAABhpD6A="
}
```

For example I want to create a new table for contact as below and transform the JSON data in below table

```
create table contact 
(
    id int, 
    FirstName nvarchar(255), 
    MiddleName nvarchar(255), 
    Surname nvarchar(255),
    Pun nvarchar(255), 
    Gender nvarchar(255),
    DateOfBirth date
)
```

I tried to parse the JSON using below query

```
WITH JSONRoot AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        Id as RowId,
        CAST(hierarchyid::GetRoot().ToString() + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NVARCHAR(4000)) + '/' AS NVARCHAR(4000)) as [HierarchyId], 
        [key],
        [value],
        CAST([type] AS INT) AS [type] 
    FROM 
        dbo.app2023
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(payload,'$') where [key] = 'Contacts'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        RowId,
        CAST(JSONRoot.[HierarchyId] + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NVARCHAR(4000)) + '/' AS NVARCHAR(4000)), 
        CASE WHEN JSONRoot.[type] = 4 THEN JSONRoot.[key]+'['+t.[key]+']' ELSE t.[key] END,
        t.[value],
        CAST(t.[type] AS INT) 
    FROM 
        JSONRoot 
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSONRoot.[value],'$') t 
    WHERE [JSONRoot].[key] like 'Contact%' and
        JSONRoot.[type] > 3 /* Only parse complex data types */
) 
SELECT 
    RowId,
    --CAST([HierarchyId] AS HierarchyId) AS [HierarchyId],
    [key],
    [value]
    --,[type]
INTO
    ParseContact2023
FROM 
    JSONRoot 
ORDER BY 
    RowId,
    [HierarchyId]
```

This helped me to parse the JSON into key and value pairs but the problem with this query is while pivoting. For every rowid it has multiple contacts so during pivoting each changes the order.

Comment: Which SQL server version do you use: the OPENJSON table-valued function can be used for this purpose and SQLServer 2017 and up, it returns a `key` column you can use to preserve the order of the contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table has an id, and the JSON text is in a column called `jsondat`; you can use the `OPENJSON` table-valued function to parse it, but capturing/preserving the order of Contacts is a little harder, like this (I didn't include all of your columns):

```sql
select T.id
    , TJSONContact.*
from YourTable T
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (T.jsondat)
        with (
          Contacts nvarchar(max) as JSON
        ) TJSON
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (TJSON.Contacts, '$.Contact')
           WITH (  FirstName    nvarchar(60)
                 , Surname      nvarchar(60)
                 , Dependants   integer
            ) as TJSONContact;
```

If you use `OPENJSON` without a `WITH` schema and supply an array, the function returns a `key` column you can use to preserve the order of the contacts.

For example, here `TJSON` has a `[key], value` set of columns.

```sql
select T.id
    , TJSONContact.*
from YourTable T
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (T.jsondat, '$.Contacts') TJSON
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (TJSON.value, '$.Contact')
           WITH (  FirstName    nvarchar(60)
                 , Surname      nvarchar(60)
                 , Dependants   integer
            ) as TJSONContact;
```

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the suggestion; I thought OP might like to combine some attributes from TJSON level. I agree with the idea but I lost the test environment; feel free to add your answer (or edit this one).